# Angular2 - Show and hide label based on other model values?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have HTML like this..

```
<label ng-if="" for="lblConcat">My label
</label>
<div>
    <span  ng-bind="model.test1"></span>
    <span  ng-bind="model.test2"></span>
    <span  ng-bind="model.test3"></span>
    <span  ng-bind="model.test4"></span>
</div>
```

I would like to show/hide label if at least one span has a value.

I know we can do with multiple expression in the Ng-If , but it is very lengthy code for checking null and empty values.

And also we can do with creating a function in the controller and call in the Ng-If. (Function loops infinity times in the page_load).

But is there any way to do in the HTML itself using angular2 attributes?

Comment: I think it should be *ngIf rather than ng-if, for angular2+

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using AngulaJS, check against Object key to determine property starting from `test` exist in the object.

```
 <label ng-if="checkValue()" for="lblConcat">My label

$scope.checkValue = function(){
  var status = false
  if(Object.keys($scope.model).some((k) => ~k.indexOf("test") && !k )){
    status = true
  }
  return status 
}
```